# Parse.com Android : Compound Queries

Tags: android, parse-platform

I want to fetch data from my Parse.com database in an Android application.

In my table I have the following columns:

> file_Type String, Message_File File, Text_Messages String, RecipientID String, SenderID String, Created_At, Updated_At

Now I want to find data for `userID` say `A123` which is present in either `RecipientID` or `SenderID`.

I tried:

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> messageQueryRecv = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Messages");
    messageQueryRecv.whereEqualTo(kosherinfotech.NGCApp.workers.Constants.RECIPIENT_IDS, currentUser.getObjectId());

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> messageQuerySend = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Messages");
    messageQuerySend.whereEqualTo(Constants.SENDER_ID,currentUser.getObjectId());

    List<ParseQuery<ParseObject>> queries = new ArrayList<ParseQuery<ParseObject>>();
    queries.add(messageQueryRecv);
    queries.add(messageQuerySend);

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> mainQuery = ParseQuery.or(queries);
    mainQuery.addDescendingOrder("createdAt");
```

Comment: What is the output/error? What is the expected one?

Comment: Thanks for reply. No error in code but it doesn't return anything. I need all the rows where either sender or receiver is the current user.

Answer (score 0):

If what you have above is your full code then your never actually querying the Parse database. You need something like this at the bottom of your code to retreive the results asynchronously.

```
mainQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
        // Results will contain the list of matches. 
        if(e == null ){
            // Matches found
        } else {
            // An error occured 
        }         
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How to select all the unique rows from two queries into one result set. i.e. say I want to find User A entry in either Column 1 or Column 2.

Comment: What you have just described doesn't match your initial question, can you please decide what you actually want. Finding unique rows is completely different to what you have above

Comment: The code I have given should find the results of both queries. The objects for the results can be found in the results paramater of the done callback function. You simply need to add the code I have given you below the code you have put in your question

Answer (score 0):

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> messageQuerySend = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>      ("Messages");

messageQuerySend.whereEqualTo(Constants.SENDER_ID,currentUser.getObjectId());
```

So far this is correct, but then after the query execute and send results back to client app you need to add the code given by JayDev as in his answer or you just can

```
List<Message> messagesList= messageQuerySend.find(); //without the call back.
```

Let me know what happens.

Comment: Using find() over findInBackground is often bad practise as find() is a synchronous method, which means unless the thread that is calling the method is already in a background task, it will cause the UI to freeze until the query has returned

Answer (score 0):

After building the you built the query Object you invoke the [query](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries) by calling findInbackground and handle the result in callback function

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> messageQueryRecv = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Messages");
messageQueryRecv.whereEqualTo(kosherinfotech.NGCApp.workers.Constants.RECIPIENT_IDS, currentUser.getObjectId());
messageQueryRecv.addDescendingOrder("createdAt");
messageQueryRecv.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

 void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
  //do something with the result
  }
 });


ParseQuery<ParseObject> messageQuerySend = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Messages");
messageQuerySend.whereEqualTo(Constants.SENDER_ID,currentUser.getObjectId());
messageQuerySend.addDescendingOrder("createdAt");
messageQuerySend.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

 void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
  //do something with the result
  }
 });
```

Comment: I want result set from both the queries in one result set I don't want to process them separately.

Comment: I was adding my queries.  No db entry with same Constants.RECIPIENT_IDS  and Constants.SENDER_ID   Now I need to check for OR condition. i.e. my user should be either one of column and I can't able to fire OR condition I hope i'M clear now

Answer (score 0):

you may have to use .include(Constants....) on your main query. If you have ParseObjects nested within other ParseObjects then they are not automatically fetched. you can use .include to let the SDK know to fetch those too OR you can fetch them manually AFTER you fetch your objects from your main query.

Taken from Parse.com

In some situations, you want to return multiple types of related objects in one query. You can do this with the include method. For example, let's say you are retrieving the last ten comments, and you want to retrieve their related posts at the same time:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Comment");

// Retrieve the most recent ones
query.orderByDescending("createdAt");

// Only retrieve the last ten
query.setLimit(10);

// Include the post data with each comment
query.include("post");

query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
  public void done(List<ParseObject> commentList, ParseException e) {
    // commentList now contains the last ten comments, and the "post"
    // field has been populated. For example:
    for (ParseObject comment : commentList) {
      // This does not require a network access.
      ParseObject post = comment.getParseObject("post");
      Log.d("post", "retrieved a related post");
    }
  }
});
```